# Bitmap and ImageView issue - problems with image width/height

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I need to display images which are stored in database and I'm having issues with image (Bitmap) width/height and ImageView ...

Just for test - when I add same image in project's drawables I can use this:

**Works:**

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.menu_image);
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), b);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bd);
```

**same as**

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_image);
```

This following **isn't working** because image isn't resized:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

**same as**

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), image));
```

Where image is constructed using this:

```
public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String b64) {
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDensity =     context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    options.inTargetDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length, options);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Image original size is 338x94.

676x188, this is image size when I'm using image from project's drawables directory. This is size that I'm looking for, in this case. I suppose a quick fix would be to use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(), but I have couple of different image formats and I would like to use imageView.setImageBitmap or imageView.setImageDrawable to behave like I loaded Bitmap from project's drawables directory.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following helper class from [github](https://github.com/ubelab/fastestpainter/blob/master/WhoIsTheFastestPainter_Lite/src/com/invenktion/android/whoisthefastestpainter/lite/utils/BitmapScaler.java)

```
public class BitmapScaler
{
// scale and keep aspect ratio
public static Bitmap scaleToFitWidth(Bitmap b, int width)
{
    float factor = width / (float) b.getWidth();
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, (int) (b.getHeight() * factor), true);
}


// scale and keep aspect ratio
public static Bitmap scaleToFitHeight(Bitmap b, int height)
{
    float factor = height / (float) b.getHeight();
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factor), height, true);
}


// scale and keep aspect ratio
public static Bitmap scaleToFill(Bitmap b, int width, int height)
{
    float factorH = height / (float) b.getWidth();
    float factorW = width / (float) b.getWidth();
    float factorToUse = (factorH > factorW) ? factorW : factorH;
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factorToUse),
            (int) (b.getHeight() * factorToUse), true);
}


    // scale and don't keep aspect ratio
    public static Bitmap strechToFill(Bitmap b, int width, int height)
     {
    float factorH = height / (float) b.getHeight();
    float factorW = width / (float) b.getWidth();
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factorW),
            (int) (b.getHeight() * factorH), true);
     }
  }
```